# nifi: prop_replace in start.sh

Tags: apache-nifi

I see that for nifi image creation many people do this in start.sh:

```
prop_replace 'nifi.web.http.port'      "${NIFI_WEB_HTTP_PORT:-8080}"
```

My understanding is that it would expose nifi.web.http.port as env variable named NIFI_WEB_HTTP_PORT, and set it to value 8080.

Am I correct?